# Function "fread()" not reading specific file types?

Tags: c++, fread

I have this snip of code in order to load some files into memory, into ***data*** .

There are three files in the same path that I would like to read: an **XML**, a **PNG** and a **TTF** font file. All three are successfully open and its size shown in ***size***. Unfortunatelly, only the **XML** and **PNG** are read into ***data***.

The **TTF** file gets the correct ***size***, the equally proper ***result*** of **fread**, but an empty (not null) ***data*** and empty **fp->_base**.

```
  char* data;
  size_t size = 0;
  FILE *fp = fopen(completeFilePath, "rb");
  if (fp != NULL) {
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    data = new char[size];
    size_t result = fread(data, sizeof(char), size, fp);
    fclose(fp);
  }
```

Could you bring some light into this problem?

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you looking at whether `data` is empty? I'm guessing that it's not actually empty, but rather just contains a null byte, and you're using functions to look at it that treat null as a string terminator.

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of `data`? **How** do you look at the contents of `data`? What should it contain? And `FILE` is an opaque structure, you should not look at its members (if they are known).

Comment: I'm looking at the contents of `data` while debugging. I can read in its contents the full **XML** file, see binary data for the **PNG** file and see only the `\0` byte with the **TFF**.

Comment: That confirms the mistake I suspected in my first comment. Answer posted explaining it in detail.

Comment: I recommend using `uint8_t` for *bytes* rather than `char`.  The `char` type *implies* that the variable contains *characters*.  Bytes may contain values that are not characters (especially non printable characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NUL byte doesn't magically mean the end of anything it's found in. It's just a convention used by a lot of C standard library functions. It's perfectly valid for a file to contain a NUL byte and then have more characters after. This is exactly what's in your `data`: a NUL byte and then more characters. So it's not actually empty; you're just incorrectly assuming that it is.

Comment: Most debuggers have a 'raw memory' view, often shown as a hex-ascii dump.  Try that.